# How to download file via Beautifulsoup in aspx?

Tags: python, asp.net, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I want to download pdf files on the website using beautiful soup and selenium.

I've written the code up to here and it's incomplete. However, since I can't find the link to download the pdf file.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import webbrowser
import os
import requests
import urllib2
import time
import urllib
try:
  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.add_argument("--headless")
  options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/bin/chromedriver", chrome_options=options)
except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
    print(e)
except urllib2.URLError:
    print ("Server down or incorrect domains.")
else:
    def not_relative_uri(href):
          return re.compile('^https://').search(href) is not None

    driver.get("https://xxxxxx")
    # print(driver.page_source.encode('utf-8'))

    my_folder="/home/python/"
    soup_res = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source.encode('utf-8'), 'html.parser')
    tr = soup_res.find("div", {"id":"pageWrapper"}).find("div", {"class":"EGZDefault-List"}).find("div", {"class":"EGZDefault-List-Info-List"}).find("table", {"class":"gridview"}).find("tbody").find_all('tr')[1:21]
```

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: That URL can't be opened.. Tried several times

Comment: @Prophet The path has been accessed successfully. Please help me try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Selenium you can do it as following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/bin/chromedriver", chrome_options=options)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
actions = ActionChains(driver)

driver.get("https://xxxxxx")

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table.gridview input[type='image']")))
time.sleep(2)
images = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("table.gridview input[type='image']")
for image in images:
    actions.move_to_element(image).perform()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    image.click()
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: The delay after click is to let the image downloaded or at least partially. Clicking on multiple downloads one after another may cause problems.

Comment: I have seen the downloaded file. However, the files are overwriting each other with the same name as new_announcement.pdf
Can you help me save under different name? (according to the order number is also possible)

Comment: The downloaded file name is given by a web site. I don't know if it is possible to change this, will try to check that later. Maybe to rename it after the file was downloaded?

Comment: I will also find a way. However, I hope you can help.

Comment: very sorry to disturb. Can you help me when clicking on image pdf will it be downloaded to a specified or random folder name  (from 1->20)?

Comment: I searched for this, as I saw it is impossible. What you can do is to move or rename each file after it was downloaded.

Comment: Yes. I did as you said. can you help me to download all paginated files?

Comment: I tried. This specific site built weird. Normally there is a next button active on the bottom until the last page is reached. Here several numbers available, then you should press `...` to present next bunch of pages... Not a friendly logics...

Comment: Are you have email?

Comment: obviously I have

Comment: Can I have your email address? I'm having a hard time in some places and I need your help

Comment: Really sorry, but not now. Too busy with my work.

Comment: Try asking cruisepandey, looks like he has a lot of time all the time :)

Comment: How can I contact him?

Comment: Commenting under any his answer, like here. Also, I see he shows his email in his profile here.

Comment: hi @cruisepandey can you help me? I sent you an email with the content that Mr.Prophet helped me, I hope you can help.

Comment: hot here... under some HIS answer